# UnicodeDecodeError when using specific python library (gender-detector)

Tags: python, python-unicode

I need to do gender guessing for some analysis, and after some research I've found this Python Library on github: [malev/gender-detector](https://github.com/malev/gender-detector)

After following the instructions and doing some tweaks (e.g. readme instructs `import gender_detector as gd` but I needed to do 
`from gender_detector import gender_detector as gd`

Then this happens, the lib has 4 datasets, 'us','uk','ar','uy', but only works when using 'us' or 'uk'

See example below:

```
from gender_detector import gender_detector as gd
detector = gd.GenderDetector('us')
detector2 = gd.GenderDetector('ar')

detector.guess('Marcos')
Out[25]: 'male'

detector2.guess('Marcos')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
detector2.guess('Marcos')

File "/home/cpneto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gender_detector/gender_detector.py", line 25, in guess
initial_position = self.index(name[0])

File "/home/cpneto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gender_detector/index.py", line 19, in call
self._generate_index()

File "/home/cpneto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gender_detector/index.py", line 25, in _generate_index
total = file.readline() # Omit headers line

File "/home/cpneto/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 1078: invalid continuation byte
```

I believe this happens because of py2 vs py3 compatibility, but I'm not sure of that and don't have any clue on how to solve this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library assumes your `ar` file is UTF-8 encoded, but it isn't (hence the `byte 0xf1 in position 1078` error). You need to either convert your file to UTF-8 or find some way to pass the actual encoding to the library.

Comment: Thank you Erik! I've found that the datasets are .csv stored on "~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gender_detector/dat‌​a"
Then I just opened the files with LibreOffice and saved without changes, LibreOffice did the utf-8 encoding for me,  now it works.